# Disable TRACK http method from tomcat 8

Tags: security, tomcat, tomcat8

How can I disable TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods from tomcat 8?

I have found a method to disable TRACE by adding `allowTrace="false"` to connector.

How can I disable the TRACK method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there are no HTTP method call TRACK. Please refer [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods). So need only block TRACE method.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to make changes in tomcat's server.xml, so added allowTrace="true"

Server.xml path = {TOMCAT_HOME}/server.xml

<Connector port="8081" **allowTrace="true"** protocol="HTTP/1.1"
connectionTimeout="20000"
redirectPort="8444" />

did the above changes, and took tomcat restart.

The above solution works for me. I hope the same will work